# Is it safe to can tomato sauce after refrigerating it?

Tags: sauce, canning, tomatoes, botulism

For my first adventure in canning, I had planned to make an arrabiata sauce and give it a hot-water bath.

I finished making the sauce around 11 p.m. before I realized I didn't have citric acid -- or even lemon juice -- to add to the jars.

So I ended up storing the sauce in an airtight container overnight and picked up the citric acid the next day. I've now got everything in jars and am suddenly wondering whether there's any danger in putting the sauce through the canning process after letting it cool for about 24 hours. I've seen other answers here saying that reboiling tomato sauce after refrigerating it creates a botulism risk, but the canning process should address that, right?

Am I safe to proceed?

Comment: Two questions: how did you store your sauce and can you link to the botulism post you mentioned, please?

Comment: @Stephie (1) After running it through a food processor, I dumped it into the pressure cooker itself, which was the only item I had large enough to hold everything. I sealed it up tight and stuck it in the fridge immediately after cooking it. (2) https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13792/how-long-should-i-cook-pasta-sauce/107672#107672 and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13792/how-long-should-i-cook-pasta-sauce/28782#28782

Comment: I see now both of those answers have negative votes, which makes me a little less concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can now can the sauce, [just reheat it first](https://www.simplycanning.com/canning-tomato-sauce/) before canning.

Comment: I don't think that's entirely safe advice. You need to ASSURE the pH is below 4.5. If it isn't then you need to properly can it. I.e. water bash or pressure can canning it. Otherwise you risk botulism which does NOT always grow bubbles or pop vacuum lids.